# Method to join line segments in a road network that are shorter than X length to an adjacent segment using ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2 and I'd like to take roads in a network shorter than a certain length and append them to an adjacent street section. Currently the road network files are split intersection to intersection which creates awkwardly small segments.

Could you suggest ways of automating the process to select all roads under a certain length and append them to an adjacent street section?

[image]

Comment: Why to green, but not one on the right? What is your criteria?

Comment: It is a segment of road that is too short, I need to append it to a longer segment of road that is on the same road. It doesn't matter whether it is appended to the green segment or the segment below but it cannot be appended to the segments to the left or right as they are different street names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate field REC using [fid]+1 in segments table
Export your short segments to separate feature class.
Export the rest to another one.

[image]

Remove from result segments with same REC, "REC" = "REC_1".
Remove from result segments with different names, "RDID" <> "RDID_1".
Sort it by the length of longest long segment:

[image]

Remove duplicates (not first) in long segment names.

[image]

Calculate additional field combo, by concatenating ([FID]+1) and road name

[image]

Make sure to use good separator, e.g “;” so you can split this field later to define road name.

Transfer value of COMBO field back to original table using 2 joins original [REC]to[REC] and original [REC]to[REC_1]

[image]

Dissolve original using that field.

[image]

Replace selected by dissolved only after computing road name in dissolved.
This will join short segment to the shortest same name neighbour segment:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do the green and blue roads have similar attributes (e.g. same road name)? Does it matter if the target blue segment is merged with the road above it and/or below it? The solution will probably involve the [Unsplit Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/unsplit-line.htm) tool. Give it a try and see how it goes. A pseudo-workflow would be something like:

1) Select by Attribute all roads under a certain length - use the SHAPE_LENGTH field or something.

2) Select by Location all roads that intersect your previous selection in #1, recursing your previous selection back against itself. This selects both your short segments and the neighboring segments you want to merge. Export this subset to a new feature class. Then delete these same subset lines from your original data.

3) Run the [Unsplit Line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/unsplit-line.htm) tool on your exported subset, specifying your "Road Name" as the *dissolve_field*, and/or any other fields whose values you want to assert as identical.

4) Data Load results back in your original data.

Assuming the data is in a .gdb, but a similar method can be done with shapefiles, coverages, etc. Also assume you have Advanced license access; Unsplit Line isn't available otherwise.

Comment: Hmmm this appears to work; however, I'd like a method that appends it to only one segment on the same road. In this case it could be either appended to the green segment or the red segment below it. In your method it combines all three segments together which can be problematic when multiple short lines exist in sequence on the same road.

Comment: I get your idea @stanleykubrick. You want to merge the short-length segment to _either_ the road above it or below it, but _not_ both. I don't know of a quick way to pop one road off your selection (the lower or upper one) in Step #2 before doing Step #3 (without having to zoom to each short-segment manually). We'll see if someone else has any ideas, but if not it may be your only option.

Answer (score 0):

Well a good way to automatize any process in ArcGis is programming AddIns is not so simple but quite effective, you can use C# or VB.NET or Phyton, it request, of course, programming knowledge.

There is a link that explain how to do it in Phyton:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//014p00000018000000

For .NET

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Developing_with_ArcGIS/0001000001ww000000/

I guess another way, more simple (i really didn't try it) is using Model Builder, there is a tutorial for this

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002w0000007v000000